# GRUB slow/irresponsive when in UEFI bios mode

Tags: bios, grub, uefi, nvidia-graphics-card, grub2

I have a GTX 1060 GPU, a ultrawide (21:9) 2560x1080 monitor and a MSI B-450 A PRO motherboard (bios version `V10.C` - 2019/11/12).

Recently i've change the bootmode of my bios from CSM to UEFI.
after this my grub started to use the monitor resolution (2560x1080), before it only supported no more than 1920x1080.

After this change the grub is EXTREMELY slow,to the level where i can see the screen beeing renderized, and i have to take care to not type too fast (not even medium speed) in the Grub shell, or it will miss the key presses.

my /etc/default/grub have this content:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="4"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="2560x1080x32"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
#GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND="efi_gop"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"

GRUB_THEME="/usr/share/grub/themes/Stylish/theme.txt"
```

two gifs showing how slow it renders:

[entering main grub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui4sm.gif)

[entering grub shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9E7v.gif)

here's the [full video link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EZRmxA23_Yg1I0F7N-y_o5-7-nidMraF) to google drive, in this video it shows also me typing (you can hear the key presses) and how slow it takes the input.

does anyone know what is happening, and how to fix it?

note: i've already tried without the custom theme, but it behaves the same way (slow)

Edit: added gif and video file

Answer (score 1):

Drawing to the screen before the OS has loaded (i.e. no accelerated driver) is very slow - basically you are thrown back to times, when computers hat 640x480x3 screens, but with 72 times the resolution.

This is not a property of GRUB, but of the screen rendering process while in [U]EFI mode: For every letter you type, the system will redraw the screen.

The best way to handle this is to just `GRUB_TERMINAL="console"` which will draw letter by lette in low resolution instead of pixel by pixel in high resolution. If you don't like the appearance, just use `GRUP_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` to display it only when really needed.

Comment: I tried the `GRUB_TERMINAL="console"`, but it made grub fallback to 480p with no colors and it boot without the nvidia video driver, so i got a 480p resolution.
Then tried the `GRUP_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` option, but it had no effect (not even in the GRUB bash), still slow.

Comment: So there's no way to grub get faster graphical rendering in UEFI?

And what about adding a resolution support in BIOS mode? since the `videoinfo` command only returns 1920x1080 as the maximum resolution

Answer (score -2):

`GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"` results in a native resolution, responsive menu for me.